A somewhat neat inequality with a simple constraint

Given $a,b,c>0$ such that $abc=1$.
Prove that:
$$3(a+b+c)-(a^2+b^2+c^2) \le 6$$

I have tried to apply Jensen's inequality for $f(x)=3x-x^2$, and homogenize the desired inequality, including the substitution $(a,b,c)\equiv\left(\frac{x}{y},\frac{y}{z},\frac{z}{x}\right)$ but I don't see a clear path to proceed with yet. Any hint/suggestion(s) would be greatly appreciated.

The substitution is great, and can lead to a solution. Use further that $xyz= 1$. Can you show what progress you've made so far?

An approach: Denote
$$f(a,b,c) = a^2+b^2+c^2+6-3(a+b+c).$$
Now, try to prove
$$f(a,b,c) \geqslant f(t,t,c) \geqslant 0, \quad t = \sqrt{ab}.$$
Note. In addition, this problem follows my old inequality
$$a^2+b^2+c^2+abc+5 \geqslant 3(a+b+c).$$
